# Import the content of a HTML page with XPath HTML Parser

Tags: feeds

I would like to import a specific item from an [HTML page](https://www.siteuptime.com/statistics.php?Id=113564&&UserId=135924), and I want to get the "Uptime" column.

I installed XPath HTML Parser and configured it; when I run it on a node, I put these details:

> XPath HTML parser Settings:
> Context: //*[@class='DataGrid']//tr[@class='Odd']

I've created an simple content type with title and body, and put the following on the mapping settings:

> xpathparser:0 TARGET => Body

When import it always says, "No new nodes."

What is happening? How can I import it?

I tried using a Firefox add-on to generate the XPath, but when I paste it on the body or the context field, it is not accepted.

Comment: May you provide a link to the project page for the module you installed?

Comment: I'm testing local

Comment: I think you have to assign a column as 'Unique GID' (or something like that, from memory). It's needed for Feeds to know if your nodes are new or if it should update existing ones.

Comment: @Andy Aren't you talking of a module you installed?

Comment: I'm just wonder how it works, because context return all the html but any value i put on the body field it does not return anything , always says, no new nodes.

Comment: Have you done the field mappings.You have mentioned that you have filled in context details.